# Make/build multiple kernel modules in different sub directories

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to make multiple kernel modules by executing one Makefile.

I have following directories and files:

- top level directory:

  - subdir0:

    - module0.c
    - Makefile
  - subdir1:

    - module1.c
    - Makefile
  - subdir2:

    - module2.c
    - Makefile
  - Makefile (I want to execute this)

I want to execute only the Makefile in the top level directory and all subdir Makefiles should be executed. I want to get one kernel module for each subdirectory.

This is my current setting but it does not work. If I execute make inside of a subdir, it builds the correct *.ko files. But if I execute the top level Makefile it just generates Module.symvers and modules.order and the output looks like every Makefile would be executed, but nothing is created inside of the subdirectories.

My top level Makefile has the following contents:

```
TARGETS := all clean
SUBDIRS := subdir0 subdir1 subdir2

.PHONY: $(TARGETS) $(SUBDIRS)

$(TARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

My subdirectory Makefiles have the following code:

```
obj-m += module0.o

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I would be glad if someone could help me.

Thanks,
micha

Comment: Make toplevel *Makefile* similar, but use `obj-y += subdir0/` and so on

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that ;)

Comment: @0andriy That's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much.
If you had written this as an answer, I had accepted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @0andriy said, I had to use a Makefile similar to the subdirectory Makefiles. But instead of adding obj-m entries, I added all subdirectories to obj-y.